# Xamarin.Forms Customize Padding for a Specific View

Tags: xamarin.forms

So I'm new to developing in Xamarin.Forms and I  was working on a project where I had multiple views in a StackLayout on one page. I was wondering if there was a way that you could specify padding differently for each different view.

For example, there is an Image that I want to fill the entire width of the screen, but there is an Entry underneath it that I do not want to fill the entire screen. However, if I use the StackLayout.Padding attribute it sets the same padding to all views.

Is there any solution to this?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention earlier that I have already tried using the margin property but keep getting the error 'Entry' does not contain a definition for 'margin'

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HuntFishNY
{
class LandingPage : ContentPage
{
    Image logo, silhouettes;
    Entry username, password;
    Button signIn, register;
    Label title, trouble;
    StackLayout heading, inputSection, footer;

    public LandingPage()
    {
        this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2B5237");


        logo = new Image();
        logo.Source = "dec_logo.png";


        silhouettes = new Image();
        silhouettes.Source = "sportinglicense_background.jpg";


        username = new Entry();
        username.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
        username.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        username.Placeholder = "Username";
        username.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
        username.TextColor = Color.Black;
        username.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;



        password = new Entry();
        password.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start;
        password.IsPassword = true;
        password.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        password.Placeholder = "Password";
        password.PlaceholderColor = Color.Gray;
        password.TextColor = Color.Black;
        password.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;

        signIn = new Button();
        signIn.Text = "Sign In";
        signIn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#2b5237");

        register = new Button();
        register.Text = "Register New Account";

        title = new Label();

        title.TextColor = Color.FromHex("#E2AF28");
        title.HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        trouble = new Label();
        trouble.Text = "Having trouble signing in?";

        heading = new StackLayout();
        heading.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;

        heading.Children.Add(logo);
        heading.Children.Add(title);
        heading.Children.Add(silhouettes);
        heading.Children.Add(username);
        heading.Children.Add(password);
        heading.Padding = new Thickness(10, 10, 20, 20);


        this.Content = heading;








        }


    }
}
```

Comment: There are many options 1) use margin for each view not padding for the stacklayout 2) put your views(controls) inside other views like (ContentView, or other StackLayout) and give them padding.3) You can create very complex layouts by nesting views but be carefull bad for perfomance

Comment: I tried to use the margin attribute but I kept getting an error saying that 'Entry' does not contain a definition for 'margin'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should be using a `Grid`(https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid/) instead of a `StackLayout`.

You can achieve different row height using `RowDefinitions` within a `Grid`.

You can also add a `StackLayout` inside another `StackLayout`.

That said, if your `Entry` do not have a `Margin` it´s probably because you're using **an outdated version of `Xamarin.Forms`** (Margin was introduced in 2.1 or 2.2. Current is 2.3)

Comment: Just to confirm, 2.2.0+ for margins